# COUNTIF function inside ISBLANK false argument

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get 2 values back (10 or 40) or blank (if the cell is blank). I've been trying a few formulas. But nothing seems to be working.

I have this (in cell B1)

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",(10))
```

this returned either blank or 10. I'm trying to get value if there's specific text in B2, the value return should be 40

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",(COUNTIF(B2,"hooray"),40,10))
```

of course this is wrong, but I hope you get the idea. Thank you so much for the help.

(I'm not very good at excel, rarely use it...sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out just now. I've added 'IF' before the 'COUNTIF' bracket, and it is good to go =D, sorry~ clumsy me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).